What if we use gravity form to return the value to field_id after pressing submit so that the value is saved in the form?
What if we use gravity form to return the value to field_id after pressing submit to save the value in the form? We want to save the value of salary in $result_analysist to save.
add_action( 'gform_after_submission_9', 'after_submission', 10, 2 );
function form_after_submission( $entry, $form ) {
foreach( $form['fields'] as $field ) {
    if( $field->label == 'name' ) {
        $name = rgar($entry, $field->id);
    } elseif ( $field->label == 'salary') {
        **$emp_salary** = rgar($entry, $field->id);
    } elseif( $field->label == 'utm_source' ) {
        $api_utm_source = rgar($entry, $field->id);
    } elseif( $field->label == 'utm_medium' ) {
        $api_utm_medium = rgar($entry, $field->id);
    } elseif( $field->label == 'utm_campaign' ) {
        $api_utm_campaign = rgar($entry, $field->id);
    } elseif( $field->label == 'utm_term' ) {
        $api_utm_term = rgar($entry, $field->id);
    } elseif( $field->label == 'utm_content' ) {
        $api_utm_content = rgar($entry, $field->id);
    } elseif( $field->label == 'result_analysis' ) {
        **$result_analysist** = rgar($entry, $field->id);
    }
}

}
What if we use gravity form to return the value to field_id after pressing submit to save the value in the form? We want to save the value of salary in $result_analysist to save.
